# CocoaPods not updating pod, compatible version for pod FirebaseFirestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I need to update my firebase pods to the last version but,  I'm getting the following error when I try to run pod update or pod install on my project

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

Analyzing dependencies

Pre-downloading: `MessageKit` from `https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit.git`, branch `3.0.0-swift5`

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseFirestore": 
In Podfile:

Firebase/Firestore was resolved to 6.14.0, which depends on
  FirebaseFirestore (~> 1.8.2)

Geofirestore was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
  FirebaseFirestore (~> 0.12.3)
```

My podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'ApproachApp' do

use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 6.14.0'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'
pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.0'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'Geofirestore'
pod 'UPCarouselFlowLayout'
pod 'MessageKit', :git => 'https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit.git', :branch => '3.0.0-swift5'
end
```

I also tried with a fresh new project and same pod config but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a 6.14.0 of Firebase/Auth?  I don't see one in the [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/6/3/6/FirebaseAuth)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the [Geofirestore pod's Firestore dependency](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/5/f/0/Geofirestore/1.2.0/Geofirestore.podspec.json#L37) to a very old beta version of Firestore.

You might want to file an issue with Geofirestore, but it looks like there hasn't been an update since July 2018 [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/5/f/0/Geofirestore).

Comment: Yes exactly. I could fix it changing to the following lines on my Podfile:

`pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'

pod 'Geofirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS.git'`